# Retrieve Text Entered In Canvas As String

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to emualate the functionality in [straightouttasomewhere.com](http://www.straightouttasomewhere.com). The user enters text into a canvas element. Next, after you either upload an image or not you see a share link for Twitter and Facebook.

These two links append the value you entered in canvas. The placeholder `{CITY}` is used, but I don't see an element with that name.

Their javascript file is difficult to follow, even when parsed. [js link](http://www.straightouttasomewhere/assets/all.js)

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="846" height="846"></canvas>
<a href="#" target="share" data-text="I'm #StraightOutta {CITY}. Where you from? #BeatsByDre" data-popwidth="550" data-popheight="420" class="button twitter"></a>
```

I would like to return the text entered and replace `{CITY}` with it.

Comment: External links are a critical part of your question. Please restate your question so we don't have to follow links to understand it. ;-)

Comment: When using a canvas, you're all on your own as far as detecting events from the dom and rendering visual elements. You can attach event listeners for clicking and keypress to the canvas, but any content you put inside a canvas is not visible to screen readers.

Comment: @AngrySpartan - There's 24,812 lines of JS in that file after it's been beautified. :eek: Since the editing happens in response to keydown events (you can tell, since the char is drawn repeatedly if the key isn't released), you should look for the code that handles that. From a quick look,  it appears that you should start 'diving down the rabbit-hole' from lines 9369 and 9398. Placing break-points on lines 9401 and 9407 allows you to single-step execution from the time a key is pressed. - Also, your JS link is broken (it's missing the `.com` immediately before `/assets`)

Comment: @enhzflep, that js source terrified me as well. This is not my Frankenstein codebase at all.

Comment: @markE, I added some further clarification.

Comment: tu retrieve the city try to use canvas.getObjecs()[0].text

Answer (score 1):

I checked the link, oh wait i know that glowing cursor..

check in the source...

```
;fabric.IText=fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Text,fabric.Observable,{type:"i-text",selectionStart:0,selectionEnd:0,s
```

Instead of emulate the behavour of that js, beautify it and study it and follow it, just fork it from github, it's free, is under the mit license and it has nice support from authors.

explore it here https://www.fabricjs.com

fork it here https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js

You can download all library or build a mini version with just the parts you need. ( canvas, staticCanvas, text, iText )

```js
function getText() {
  alert(canvas.getObjects()[0].text);
}
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.add(new fabric.IText("STRAIGHT\nOUTTA\n ", {textAlign: 'center', active: true}));
```

```html
<button onClick="getText()" >GET THE TEXT</button>
<script src="http://www.deltalink.it/andreab/fabric/fabric.js" ></script>
        <canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=400 style="height:200px;width:500px;"></canvas>
```